# Saving work in R, changing the working directory, and I keep getting the message 'permission denied'

Tags: r

I'm new to R (and coding in general) and I'm having various issues with saving my work onto my PC (using Windows 10). In R I've been using tidyverse and gapminder. I've used various different paths to save my work but none of them seem to work. I read that Windows users should only use forward slashes or double backslashes in their paths for the working directory but the paths to my folders only use single backslashes (I'm not sure if the path in the working directory should be exactly what it is in my files so this could be the issue). This is what happens when I try to get my working directory (uses forward slashes which doesn't technically exist in my files):

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/sarah/OneDrive/r projects"
```

This is what happens when I try to save my work:

```
> read.csv("C:/Users/sarah/OneDrive/r projects", header = TRUE)
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/sarah/OneDrive/r projects': Permission denied
```

Is there a problem with the code I typed in? Should I be including 'gapminder.csv' somewhere in the path?
Another issue that comes up is that the permission is denied. This is the only path in my terminal that asked if I can allow access to it (to unblock the firewall):

```
C:\Users\sarah\Documents>
```

Is there a way I can add a path to the terminal to unblock the firewall?
Another issue is that I can't change my working directory. This is what happens when I type:

```
> setwd("C:\Users\sarah\Documents")
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
```

Of course it didn't work because of the backslashes. I've tried so many different paths to change to the working directory but I won't put them all here. I've tried changing the slashes to forward or double backslashes and changing the locations to so many different places. I even tried contacting Microsoft to see if it was a problem with OneDrive but they couldn't really help me.

Comment: Try with `read.csv("C:/Users/sarah/OneDrive/r projects/gapminder.csv")`

Comment: The `Error: '\U'` is because in R, you need to double-backslash, so `setwd("c:\\Users\\sarah\\Documents")`, since the `\ ` is typically an escaping-character. Personally I find that distracting, so I tend to use the forward-slash, `setwd("c:/Users/sarah/Documents")`, which works everywhere (even on windows). As to the permission-denied error, could be lots of things, but in general I discourage operating on a onedrive mount, as it can be the source of many file-locking problems. Try working in a non-onedrive path and see if you get the same problems. (Copy files over to onedrive later.)

Comment: Ahh, but I missed a key point that @stefan hinted at. `read.csv` needs a *file* to open, and it seems like that your `r projects` is a *directory*. For instance, `read.csv("~/Downloads")` will fail (same error), but `read.csv("~/Downloads/mt.csv")` works, because the former is a directory and the latter is a file.

Answer (score 0):

As @stefan indicated in the comments, you need a full path and file name to the csv file you are trying to open.  If your file is located in the directory "C:\Users\sarah\OneDrive\r projects", then you would need to also include the file name.  In addition, you need to read the data into a variable so you can work with it.  The full code would look something like this:

```
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/sarah/OneDrive/r projects/gapminder.csv", header = TRUE)
```

You may have to adjust the path if your file is in a different location.

Once your data is in the variable `df`, then you can start performing other operations on it.  You might want to check out some beginner level tutorials.